# 2014 Honda CRV, LX Trim Package

Tags: honda, tires, crv, wheels

I purchased a 2014 Honda CR-V, LX trim Package.  It came stock with the metal 16 inch wheels and 215 70 R 16 tires.  The specs on the tire are:
Diameter 27.9 inches
Wheel 16 inches
Sidewall 5.9 inches
Width of the tire 8.5 inches
Revolutions per mile 725

I have found a nice set of Alloy Wheels, from a 2014 CR-V EX trim package, that are 17 inch.
If I put the Michelin Defender 215/65 R17 Tires on these rims, and put them on the CRV LX trim package.  The specs on these tires are:

Diameter 28 inches
Wheel 17 inch
Sidewall Profile 5.5 inches
Width of the tire 8.5 inches
Revolutions per mile 721

If I change these wheels out, will I have any issue.  I have had a mechanic tell me that with the speed sensing settings in the computer, that it would cause issue.  He recommended to not do it.  Can I change the wheels and not have any issue.  Or can I change the wheels and tires, and have the computer adjusted to accept the change.

It seems odd to me that an 1/10th of an inch in diameter, 4/10th inch difference in sidewall, and 4 revolutions per mile could have impact.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

This has been discussed before, but you've done your homework and the short answer is "negligible impact".

Long answer is that the odometer, speedometer, transmission shift points, ECU inputs, and every other "speed-dependent" function will be affected.  But 4 revs/mile is very little to be concerned about.  The same discrepancy could easily be caused by the original tires with under-inflation.

No worries!